# Import standard Python library from C

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-extension

I am writing a [Python 3 C extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) where I want to use a MappingProxyType (`from types import MappingProxyType`). From what I saw in the Cpython source code, MappingProxyType is written in Python and not in C.

How can I use this type from C? I imagine there must be something like an C-level "import" and then I could find the PyObject (or rather, PyTypeObject) from the name as a C string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html) for for importing modules. Then you just need to get the `MappingProxyType` type attribute from the module:

```
static PyTypeObject *import_MappingProxyType(void) {
    PyObject *m = PyImport_ImportModule("types");
    if (!m) return NULL;
    PyObject *t = PyObject_GetAttrString(m, "MappingProxyType");
    Py_DECREF(m);
    if (!t) return NULL;
    if (PyType_Check(t))
        return (PyTypeObject *) t;
    Py_DECREF(t);
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not the MappingProxyType type");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check for errors on the getattr.  In practice it is unlikely to fail, but somebody could have monkey-patched out the module.

Comment: @Kevin it's not necessary. If `t` is `NULL`, the function just returns `NULL`. `t` never gets used, so it's safe.

Comment: And what if `t` is `None` or something that isn't a `PyTypeObject`?